# Is there a consensus on the "heaviness" of rain?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting, rainfall, rain

As part of the home dashboard I am developing, I get information about incoming rain. It is given in mm/min.

Is there a consensus on the precipitation rate that is called "*light rain*", or "*heavy rain*"? (I would like, if this is possible, to use some standardized naming)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The German Weather Service (Deutscher Wetterdienst, DWD) provides the following definitions:

> Heavy rain is defined as large amounts of precipitation during a fixed period of time. [...]
>
> The DWD issues warnings of heavy rain using three categories:
>
> - heavy rain: 15 to 25 l/m² within 1 hour or 20 to 35 l/m² within 6 hours
> - severly heavy rain: 25 to 40 l/m² within 1 hour or 35 to 60 l/m² within 6 hour
> - extremely heavy rain: above 40 l/m² within 1 hour or above 60 l/m² within 6 hour

Source: https://www.dwd.de/DE/service/lexikon/begriffe/S/Starkregen.html and https://www.dwd.de/DE/wetter/warnungen_aktuell/kriterien/warnkriterien.html?nn=508722#doc453962bodyText3, translation my own.

---

Heavy rain is distinct from constant rain by the period of time, over which the rain falls, as well as the total amount of rain per m². Still, heavy rain events may be part of constant rain periods.

Answer (score 6):

If there was a worldwide standard, then WMO would have imposed it to its members. Here are the definitions in the American (NOAA/NWS) standard

([summarized at NJWeatherScan](http://www.njweatherscan.com/definitions_of_precipitation.htm), initially from manuals like [this one (PDF page 66, page label 58)](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/Order_JO_7900.5E.pdf):

Light rain: falling rate of less than 2.54 mm/h.  This would be < 0.042 mm/min.

Moderate rain: falling rate of more than 2.8 mm/h, but less than 7.6 mm/h.  This would be 0.042 mm/min - 0.127 mm/min.

Heavy rain: falling rate of more than 7.6 mm/h. This would be > 0.127 mm/min.

So clearly different standards [compared to the DWD answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/22533/6298) (note: 1 l/m² is equivalent to 1mm). Nowadays, automated weather stations use rain gauges with sensors, so a modern station with the computer inside has a clear and accurate computation of rain/snow falling rates. But there is no universal standards.

Comment: Since you reference the other answer, you should point out that DWD's use of l/m^2 corresponds to 1mm in NOAA's definition.